# How to obtain scoring between 0 and 1 with ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

Currently, I've indexed many documents in ElasticSearch and when I did a search on max score,  the number exceeds 1.

How can I obtain a similarity search, which is between 0 and 1 ?

Should I configure ElasticSearch better ? or I should change my mapping?

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene scoring is not classical cosinus-similarity function based on tif id vectors, but some modification wich takes into account other factors like boost on field or query terms. You can read a mode details about scoring formula at [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html). So the simplest way to get scoring between a 0.0 and 1.0, just norm score on max_score from elasticsearch response (it coincides with score of the first document).

Comment: How can I normalize score using max_score using score script?